Synonymize [aad-b2c] to [azure-ad-b2c]
At some point the tag aad-b2c popped up, but it's an (undefined/undescribed, other than to say that it's a duplicate/synonym) exact synonym of the much more-used, better-named, and better-defined tag azure-ad-b2c. In fact, all but 4 questions tagged with aad-b2c are also tagged with azure-ad-b2c.
Can aad-b2c please be made a synonym of azure-ad-b2c?

I mostly expected the feature to now be officially called "Entra ID B2C" but oddly it's not; it's, confusingly specifically documented to be different service (to the Azure AD we used to have?). Ahh Microsoft, you do love confusing us...

@ThomA I would also support synonymizing [tag:azure-active-directory] to [tag:microsoft-entra-id] but I figured I'd go one step at a time... especially given most people don't yet refer to Azure AD as Entra ID, FWIW.

The documentation explicitly state's it's not the same thing, TylerH, that was my point: "Azure AD B2C is built on the same technology as Microsoft Entra ID but for a different purpose and is a separate service." So Microsoft renamed Azure AD to Entra ID, and then released a new/retained an existing product, which has Azure AD in its name but isn't Entra ID... I was just ranting about MS' naming "choices".

@ThomA Mea culpa, I mistyped at first--see my edited comment, which specifies "Azure AD", not "Azure AD B2C". The new name would be either "Azure AD B2C" or "Microsoft Entra B2C" (if they want to be consistent).

Ahh yes, we've "crossed wires".

I know it is off-topic, but I think the tag synonyms page should gain more visibility. You can see some of the pending approval entries have been hanging there for more than a year.

Lowering the threshold to accept the proposal would go a long way, @Ray . Currently it needs 5 users to agree (1 to propose, 4 to agree); not even close/reopen actions needs that any more (on Main).

@ThomA That's not even the worst of it--you need to have a score of 5 or more in a tag to recommend synonymization for it :-( That is a sensible restriction in one sense, but I think users over a certain rep threshold like 10k or 20k should be able to propose them as well, given 4 other users are needed to make anything happen on it.

I thought that was the case, @TylerH , but have have a score of 5 or more in all the current pending suggestions, so I couldn't test.

@ThomA I agree that the current threshold could be too high. Meanwhile, I am just considering the possibility of maybe introducing a separate review queue. Currently, that page is quite shady IMO and I think many users don't even know that page exists.

Agreed. I've both synonymised and merged these tags.
updating post history, 38 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 37 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 4 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'aad-b2c': [aad-b2c] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 6125
tag remapping of [azure-ad-b2c] and [aad-b2c] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
16 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
26 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym aad-b2c -> azure-ad-b2c was approved!

